# Angular material autocomplete - make sure something is selected

Tags: angular, autocomplete

I'm using angular material autocomplete to allow users to select a company from a long list.

For example it initially populated the list with: Apple, Google, Microsoft, etc., and when the user types "G", it only filters Google. How do I ensure one of the items has been selected? For example, my form can be submitted even though somebody has only typed 'G' or 'Google', but the autocomplete doesn't register properly unless somebody actually clicks the "Google" on the list. Can I use some type of material validator or angular Forms validator to make the form invalid unless an actual option is selected from the list (versus text types into the field)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are asking, but if you want to ensure an option is selected try to add `required` attribute and include a validation process in your `ngAfterViewInit`:

```
import { MatAutocompleteTrigger } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
//....

  @ViewChild(MatAutocompleteTrigger) trigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.trigger.panelClosingActions.subscribe((e) => {
      if (!(e && e.source)) {
        this.myControl.setValue('');
        this.trigger.closePanel();
      }
    });
  }
```

in the template:

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>Number</mat-label>
    <input type="text" required <!-- here -->
           placeholder="Pick one"
           aria-label="Number"
           matInput
           [formControl]="myControl"
           [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

working [demo](http://%20%20https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-autocomplete-force-selection-of-option?file=src/app/autocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example.ts)

Comment: That only checks whether the INPUT is empty or not, and I can type anything in there to validate the form. I need to make sure an option is selected via MAT-AUTOCOMPLETE

Comment: Oh ok i see what you want ... i'll update my answer